# Not able to connect Jboss server 7 using IP

Tags: wifi, jboss7.x

I am just trying to create a simple servlet on my PC which I want to open from my mobile.

I am using JBoss and final version to run the servlet. I am able to open in `localhost:8080`, But I am trying to open from my mobile using my PC's public IP it's not able to connect. My PC  and mobile are in the same WiFi network.

I also tried by changing the configuration file i.e

```
 -<interface name="public">

<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/> to 0.0.0.0

</interface>
```

Still not working. Please guide me what to do further. Do I have to off my PC's firewall to do it.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start JBoss AS with `-b 0.0.0.0` to listen on any IP. You should see a message on the console indicating it's listening on `0.0.0.0:8080`.

You'll also have to open port 8080 on your firewall. How you do that will be specific to your operating system.

Comment: I am using a JBOSS AS 7 ... Dont have the option of -b I am running the standalone.bat from cmd

Comment: I'm pretty sure that option has always been there.

Comment: In fact I just tested on 7.1.1.Final and it worked fine.